How does positive current flow out of the negative terminal (2A) and into the positive terminal (2A)?
Does the battery act like a resistor with a 10V voltage drop now?

You don't have a battery in your circuit. Are you referring to the 10V voltage source (in series with the 2R resistor), or something else?

Not like a resistor, just like an ideal voltage source that maintains the same voltage difference across its terminals regardless of how much current flows into or out of it and in what direction.

Does (positive) current flow into the positive terminal and out of the negative terminal? That is, electron current flows into the negative terminal and out of the positive terminal? Does it sustain a voltage drop across that? Will this circuit continue to work as such?

By all of which I mean, there is still a voltage drop across the battery in this case, not a voltage rise?

Voltage drop and rise are only relative terms based solely on the sign shown on the voltage source itself. All you know for sure is that the voltage at the + terminal is 10V more than the voltage at the - terminal.

That is, the electrons in the current lose energy going from the side of the battery it enters and out of the side it leaves?

In your example, yes.

@WondrousConfusion Yes - if this were a physical battery, it would be charging (if the chemistry allows the reaction to proceed in reverse), or possibly overheating/experiencing chemical breakdown from the energy imparted onto it (if impossible to recharge)
